# Docker depends_on Order Not Working

Tags: java, selenium, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to a selenium hub, chrome node, and firefox node, and my code that runs the test execution script in that order. I have the nodes depending on the hub and the code depending on both hubs. However, running `docker-compose --build` builds the code first and tries to run without starting the selenium components. I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    networks:
      robottestsnw: {}
    ports:
    - 4444:4444

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    networks:
      robottestsnw: {}
    depends_on:
      - hub
    shm_size: '2g'
    environment:
      SCREEN_WIDTH: 1920
      SCREEN_HEIGHT: 1080
      HUB_HOST: hub


  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    networks:
      robottestsnw: {}
    depends_on:
      - hub
    shm_size: '2g'
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      SCREEN_WIDTH: 1920
      SCREEN_HEIGHT: 1080
      HUB_HOST: hub

  robottests:
    build: .
    networks:
      robottestsnw: {}
    depends_on:
      - chrome
      - firefox

networks:
  robottestsnw:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile

# Base image
FROM sgrio/java-oracle

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

# Copy test project files to the image folder
COPY . /frontend-integration-tests

# Make the folder as a working directory
WORKDIR /frontend-integration-tests

# Install the test project libraries
RUN mvn package
CMD ["java", "-cp", "target/automated-testing 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "automated-testing.service.App"]
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you run `docker-compose --build up` , right?

Comment: Are yuo deploying in swarm mode. Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: Thanks for the information @ConstantinGalbenu It looks like my issue was with the last run command in the dockerfile. mvn package also runs the test. I replaced the CMD command with mvn package and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker-compose up
```

It starts services in dependency order, about *docker-compose --build up* don't sure. And maybe your port, network name are defined wrong:

```
hub:
image: selenium/hub
networks:
 - robottestsnw
ports:
 - 4444:4444
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to help other people looking for answers about the same topic, could you provide more detail about how to resolve the issue the original poster (OP) was having.